# OpenTelemetry migration from OpenCencus to add Metrics to Azure Insights

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

Currently trying to migrate from OpenCensus to OpenTelemtry, and running into one or two issues.

My metrics are logging to Azure App Insights, but I've no idea how to get them into the category I want.

They're currently going into `azure.applicationinsights`, but I want them to go into `vm0_unhealthy`

[image]

I tried using views, but ended up with lots of string errors - and the docs are far from clear.

Code I'm using below

```
exporter = AzureMonitorMetricExporter.from_connection_string(
    os.environ["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
)

meter = metrics.get_meter_provider().get_meter("view-name-change")
counter = meter.create_counter(vm_number)
  
# Log results
logging.info(f"Emitting metric for {vm_number}: 1")
counter.add(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I too faced a similar issue @Stuart.Sklinar and I have raised a [bug request](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-monitor-opentelemetry-python/issues/3) and below are my observations:

```
from opentelemetry import metrics
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import Counter, MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import PeriodicExportingMetricReader
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorMetricExporter

rexporter = AzureMonitorMetricExporter.from_connection_string(
    "InstrumentationKey=a2dec36ee8df;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
)
rithreader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(rexporter, export_interval_millis=5000)
metrics.set_meter_provider(MeterProvider(metric_readers=[rithreader]))
test = {
    "Name": "Rithwik"
}
rithmeter = metrics.get_meter("testname")
rithcounter = rithmeter.create_counter("testcounter")
rithcounter.add(1, test)
```

Using above code I am not unable to set the metric namespace testname, because of which i opened a bug request.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just don't think it work - *however* the latest version documents something where this does work